# Extracting a value 5 minutes away from the current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, timestamp

I have the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02', '2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02'],
'Time':['09:59:50.024','09:59:50.623','10:00:15.124','10:00:15.148','10:00:42.552','10:04:49.782','10:05:14.896','10:05:41.719','10:05:45.050','10:08:19.170'], 
'midquote': [0.0,0.0,14.145,14.145,14.245,14.360,14.305,14.235,14.295,14.285]})
```

I want to extract the midquote 5 minutes after the time of each row. It's impossible to get exact 5 minutes difference so the time closest to 5 minutes (must be less than) is preferable.

Desired output

```
pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02', '2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02'],
'Time':['09:59:50.024','09:59:50.623','10:00:15.124','10:00:15.148','10:00:42.552','10:04:49.782','10:05:14.896','10:05:41.719','10:05:45.050','10:08:19.170'], 
'midquote': [0.0,0.0,14.145,14.145,14.245,14.360,14.305,14.235,14.295,14.285], 
'timestamp':['2020-01-02 09:59:50.024000','2020-01-02 09:59:50.623000','2020-01-02 10:00:15.124000','2020-01-02 10:00:15.148000','2020-01-02 10:00:42.552000','2020-01-02 10:04:49.782000','2020-01-02 10:05:14.896000','2020-01-02 10:05:41.719000','2020-01-02 10:05:45.050000','2020-01-02 10:08:19.170000'],
'timestamp_5_min':['2020-01-02 10:04:49.782000','2020-01-02 10:04:49.782000','2020-01-02 10:05:14.896000','2020-01-02 10:05:14.896000','2020-01-02 10:05:41.719000','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan'],
 'midquote_5_min':[14.360,14.305,14.235,14.295,14.285,'nan','nan','nan','nan','nan']})
```

I tried the following code but it didn't work

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time)
df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'], inplace=True)
df['midquote'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
mid = df[['Instrument','timestamp','midquote']]
mid['5_min_timestamp'] = mid.timestamp
mid.rename(columns={'midquote':'5_min_midquote'}, inplace=True)
pd.merge_asof(df, mid, on='timestamp', by=['Instrument'], tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5min"), direction='forward', allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Also, if I did not `sort_values`, it will give an error of `left keys must be sorted`

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: for example for the first row of `midquote_5_min`, how did you get `15.00`? There are no values of 15 within the sample data. You need to create a minimum reproducible example, as it's impossible to test and help solve with the existing input data.

Comment: @DavidErickson I edited the dafaframe. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem was using `.searchsorted` to to return the index + 1 of the nearest date/time between the column `Time` and the column that is `Time` + 5 minutes called `timestamp_5_min`. From there,  I did some messy merging, column renaming and column dropping, which could probably be cleaner but gets the job done.

input:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':['A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M'], 
'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02', '2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02'],
'Time':['09:59:50.024','09:59:50.623','10:00:15.124','10:00:15.148','10:00:42.552','10:04:49.782','10:05:14.896','10:05:41.719','10:05:45.050','10:08:19.170'], 
'midquote': [0.0,0.0,14.145,14.145,14.245,14.360,14.305,14.235,14.295,14.285]})
```

code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['timestamp_5_min'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5))
df['timestamp_5_min_new'] = df['Time'].searchsorted(df['timestamp_5_min'])-1
df1 = df[['Time', 'midquote']]
df2 = pd.merge(df,df1,how='left',left_on='timestamp_5_min_new', right_index=True)
df2.loc[df2['timestamp_5_min_new'] == max(df2['timestamp_5_min_new']), ['timestamp_5_min_new', 'Time_y', 'midquote_y']] = np.nan
df2 = df2.drop(['timestamp_5_min_new','timestamp_5_min', 'midquote_x'], axis=1).rename({'Time_x': 'Time', 'Time_y': 'timestamp_5_min', 'midquote_y' : 'midquote'}, axis=1)
df2
```

output:

```
    Instrument Date Time                    timestamp_5_min         midquote
0   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 09:59:50.024 2020-07-16 10:04:49.782 14.360
1   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 09:59:50.623 2020-07-16 10:04:49.782 14.360
2   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:00:15.124 2020-07-16 10:05:14.896 14.305
3   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:00:15.148 2020-07-16 10:05:14.896 14.305
4   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:00:42.552 2020-07-16 10:05:41.719 14.235
5   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:04:49.782 NaT                     NaN
6   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:05:14.896 NaT                     NaN
7   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:05:41.719 NaT                     NaN
8   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:05:45.050 NaT                     NaN
9   A2M 2020-01-02  2020-07-16 10:08:19.170 NaT                     NaN
```

---

Answer #2 with Grouping by Instrument. This makes it a little bit more challenging, but the below gets the job done.

I have changed some of the sample data, so that there are two categories now, and I have changed the time difference requirement to 25 seconds.

Step #1 - Use `.groupby`, `.transform` `'lambda x` and `searchsorted` together in order to find the index of the nearest time value closest to `25 seconds` (the parameter  passed to p`pd.Timedelta`) for this exercise.

Step #2 - The line where I create the dictionary `a` is essentially used in order to find the max index by group for `Instrument` which is 3 and 9 respectively.

Step #3 - From there, create a temporary that shows the max index for each instrument and any row where the max index is > than the `timestamp_5_min_new` column. This essentially means there are no rows after that group that are within 25 seconds, so they are turned to `NaN` in the `np.where()` statement. From there, just clean up the columns and column names.

input:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Instrument':
                   ['B3M','B3M','B3M','B3M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M','A2M'],
                   'Date':['2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02', '2020-01-02',
                           '2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02','2020-01-02'],
                   'Time':['09:59:50.024','09:59:50.623','10:00:15.124','10:00:15.148','10:00:42.552',
                           '10:04:49.782','10:05:14.896','10:05:41.719','10:05:45.050','10:08:19.170'],
                   'midquote': [0.0,0.0,14.145,14.145,14.245,14.360,14.305,14.235,14.295,14.285]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

code:

```
df['timestamp_5_min'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=25))
df['timestamp_5_min_new'] = df.groupby(['Instrument'])['Time'].transform(lambda x: x).searchsorted(df.groupby(['Instrument'])['timestamp_5_min'].transform(lambda x: x))
a = {v: k for k, v in df['Instrument'].drop_duplicates(keep='last').to_dict().items()}
df['temp'] = df['Instrument'].map(a)
df1 = df[['Time', 'midquote']]
df2 = pd.merge(df,df1,how='left',left_on='timestamp_5_min_new', right_index=True)
df2['Time_y'] = np.where((df2['timestamp_5_min_new'] > df2['temp']), np.datetime64('NaT'), df2['timestamp_5_min'])
df2['midquote_y'] = np.where((df2['timestamp_5_min_new'] > df2['temp']), np.nan, df2['midquote_y'])
df2 = df2.drop(['timestamp_5_min_new','timestamp_5_min', 'midquote_x', 'temp'], axis=1).rename({'Time_x': 'Time', 'Time_y': 'timestamp_5_min', 'midquote_y' : 'midquote'}, axis=1)
df2
```

output:

```
    Instrument  Date    Time                    timestamp_5_min       midquote
0   B3M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 09:59:50.024 2020-07-17 10:00:15.024 14.145
1   B3M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 09:59:50.623 NaT                 NaN
2   B3M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:00:15.124 NaT                 NaN
3   B3M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:00:15.148 NaT                 NaN
4   A2M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:00:42.552 2020-07-17 10:01:07.552 14.360
5   A2M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:04:49.782 2020-07-17 10:05:14.782 14.305
6   A2M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:05:14.896 2020-07-17 10:05:39.896 14.235
7   A2M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:05:41.719 2020-07-17 10:06:06.719 14.285
8   A2M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:05:45.050 2020-07-17 10:06:10.050 14.285
9   A2M     2020-01-02  2020-07-17 10:08:19.170 NaT                 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I `groupby(['Instrument', 'Date'])` in this case? I tried putting it at `df['Time'].groupby(['Instrument', 'Date']).searchsorted` but it didn't work

Comment: @ShaunLim that made things much more complicated and it's not the cleanest, but hopefully it got the job done. Very challenging question. I wonder if there is a much easier way.